# Does this special relativistic identity hold in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, velocity

So I came across the following identity in the fascinating book: "Beyond the Einstein Addition Law and it's Gyroscopic Thomas Precession":

$$\gamma_{u \oplus v} = \gamma_u \gamma_v\left(1 + \frac{u \cdot v}{c^2}\right) $$

Where $u$ and $v$ are $3$ vectors and $u \oplus v$ is [Einstein's famous velocity addition law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula):

$$u \oplus v =  \left(\frac{1}{1+u\cdot v / c^2}\right)\left(u + \frac{v}{\gamma_u }+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\gamma_u}{1+\gamma_u}(u\cdot v) u\right)$$

Now, an addition law and the gamma factor can be defined for any spacetime (in general relativity). This begs the question does:

$$\gamma_{u \oplus v} = \gamma_u \gamma_v\left(1 + \frac{u \cdot v}{c^2}\right) $$

still hold in any spacetime?

Comment: My intuition (but I may be wrong) is that Special Relativity laws are still valid (locally) also in General Relativity (locally, GR is SR).  This means that the addition is valid as long as the two objects moving with $u$ and $v$ are "close" to each other.

Comment: @Quillo I thought that too. But locally the $\gamma$ factor is not the same as that obtained in SR so I have my doubts.

Comment: If $u,\,v$ are parallel, this result reduces to rapidities being additive, and hence the closure of the Lorentz group. In the general case, [gyrogroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrovector_space#Axioms) are needed. So your question amounts to whether gyrovector spaces still work properly in GR.

Comment: @J.G. indeed. I avoided that terminology since I thought it would reduce the chances of me getting an answer.

Comment: I think it's simpler: 4-velocity is always well defined in GR, from 4-vel (aka "absolute velocity") you have to understand how to obtain the "relative speed" and the associated Lorentz factor (this is quite standard, see e.g. SECTION 3.2 HERE https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0603009). Finally, check that the addition law works as in SR.